# error.response is undefined in catch axios

Tags: javascript, axios, fetch, response, interceptor

My problem is `error.response` - undefined.
It happens because I have an interceptor:

```
instance.interceptors.response.use(undefined, error => {
  if (error.response.status === 401) {
    console.log("UNAUTHORIZED");
  }
});
```

If I remove the interceptor everything will work. 
This is how I want to get the response from error:

```
const fn = async stuff => {
  try {
    const res = await API.get('bla-bla-bla')
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e.response) <------------------------- undefined
    if (e.response && e.response.status === 401) {
      console.log("UNAUTHORIZED");
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your interceptor you must return the error object with Promise.reject for it to be available later:

```js
instance.interceptors.response.use(undefined, error => {
  if (error.response.status === 401) {
    console.log("UNAUTHORIZED");
  }
  return Promise.reject(error);
});
```

Comment: Great! Thank you for help!